# How to wait for ComputerVision getReadResult or getReadResultAsync methods to complete?

Tags: java, azure, rx-java

How can I wait for the Observable that getReadResultAsync method returns to complete? Or make sure that getReadResult() returns the complete result without checking the status in a while loop.

Package: `com.microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.ComputerVision;`

`readResults = computerVission.getReadResult(operationId);`

While loop checking:

> quate

```
ReadOperationResult readResults = null;
boolean pollForResult = true;
while (pollForResult) {
            readResults = computerVission.getReadResult(operationId);

            if (readResults != null) {

                OperationStatusCodes status = readResults.status();

                if (status == OperationStatusCodes.FAILED || status == OperationStatusCodes.SUCCEEDED) {
                    pollForResult = false;
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that getReadResult() returns the complete result without checking the status in a while loop. You can try with the below code:

```
ReadOperationResult readResults = null;
boolean pollForResult = true;

if(readResults != null){
return readResults;
}
else{
 OperationStatusCodes status = readResults.status();
 
if (status == OperationStatusCodes.FAILED|| status == OperationStatusCodes.SUCCEEDED) {
                pollForResult = false;
            }}
```